# Jersey Freemarker MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, jersey, freemarker

I try to configure jersey-mvc-freemarker on TomEE 1.7.2. But I can't ...

Configure Jersey

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig{
    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("my.pack.controllers")
        .property(MvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH, "/WEB-INF/classes/my/pack")
        .register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.freemarker.FreemarkerMvcFeature.class);

    }

}
```

Controller

```
@Path("main")
public class MainController {

    @Inject
    private TestBean bean;

@GET
public Viewable getIt() {

        return new Viewable("test");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">

    <display-name>ui</display-name>
</web-app>
```

I put my test.ftl to my.pack

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/resources/main I get message

> No message body writer has been found for response class Viewable.

Thanks you

**UPDATE:**

I configured tracing in Jersey and got:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Error processing webservice request


        org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:98)


org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        java.lang.NullPointerException
            org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:227)
            org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:94)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.62 (1.7.2) logs.
```

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: I have no error message, and I have no Exception. But when I am debugging I see that FreemarkerViewProcessor is not initialized.

Comment: I configured tracing in Jersey and got:

Comment: Seems to be what I suspected. TomEE has it's own JAX-RS implementation (CXF). Your Jersey configuration may not even be used. You may need to figure out how to disable the CXF so you can use Jersey, or actually _use_ CXF, or Use a different server. If you need full EE support, maybe Glassfish (which uses Jersey), or if you don't need the EE support, just use vanilla Tomcat. I'm thinking the reason it _seems_ to work for the resources is that by not overriding `getClasses` or `getResources` in an `Application` subclass (which ResourceConfig is), the JAX-RS spec states that the classpath ...

Comment: .. should be scanned for resources and providers. So it may seem that the Jersey `packages(...)` is working, but really it's just the CXF classpath scanning that's picking up the resources and loading them into _it's_ application. I am not sure about all this, but it it seems this is the case, as the stacktrace shows CXF classes.

Comment: You might be able to test out this theory by creating a simple resource class and trying to `register(TheClasses.class);` in side the above `JerseyConfig` constructor. See if it can be accessed